# How can I clear off the stripes in the image? android camera2 fps or banding problem

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2, stripes

I'm working on a camera application with Android camera2. Too many black stripes appear in the image when the camera is turned on.

[image: the image]

I think this is an FPS issue. When the photo is taken, these stripes disappear and a beautiful image is obtained. When I look at the fps supported by the camera with code: `Range<Integer>[] ranges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);`, I see that it is much higher than it should be. The only range value is [5000-60000]. And i could'nt set the FPS range by `previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, getRange());` code, due to not supported fps range error. Here is my Camera session code:

```
private void createCameraSession() {
        try {
            previewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
            previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try {
                        mCameraCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE_50HZ);
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE, CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_SIMPLE);
                        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, false);
                        zoom.setZoom(previewRequestBuilder, zoomFactor);
                        CaptureRequest previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                        Log.d("TAG", "preview build is done");
                        mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest, null, mHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            }, mHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've tried many combination of AE and AWB modes but it wasn't work. The problem continues. Is there another way to set the target FPS range of the camera or the Surface? The api of my device Android 5.1, so `Surface.setFrameRate()` function doesn't work. Can anybody help me for the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

First, Android 5.1 had a bug about reporting frame rate ranges - you'll need to divide the numbers from available target FPS range by 1000 for setting frame rate (so that'd be [5, 60] fps).

Second, this is very likely a problem with your lights. Most light sources flicker at some rate (60 or 50 Hz for old-fashioned lightbulbs or fluorescent lights. All sorts of hz between 60 and 200 for LED), and the camera autoexposure has to account for that or banding will happen.

Normally, antibanding algorithms will detect the flicker or banding and adjust exposure time to remove it.  But your old device may not be able to handle modern LED light flicker.

Try the device outdoors and see if sunlight has banding to figure out if the lights are the problem.

Unfortunately, if lights are your problem, you may have trouble finding a way around this. You could tweak exposure compensation but that'll also make the image darker or brighter, and may still have banding.  And I doubt your device supports manual control, and then you'd have to write your own autoexposure routine, which is complicated to do well.

Comment: As i emphasize at question previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, getRange()); method doesn't work. Unfortunatley i couldn't set the frame rate as [5, 60]. When i did it, i got unsupported fps range error. And regardless of light, the stripes appear at the screen.